# How to make pixel perfect Line2D in - Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

G'day, I have JPanel with some Line2D objects on it. Issue is when I draw this line it doesn't appear as I want them to. Lines are not smooth, It's hard to explain in word so I am posting an Image,

[image]

Zoomed Area,

[image]

How to make them look more polished rather than wrinkly.

Thanks

Comment: Don't know java well, and don't know swing well: but I think your looking for anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is likely that you don't have antialiasing turned on your Graphics context. Try the following line before you draw:

```
graphics.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

(where, of course, `graphics` is your Graphics2D instance).

Later on when you discover that the *text* you're drawing is also ugly and jagged, you'll want to use

```
graphics.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

However, text is a little more complicated; there's several values for this hint that you can use depending on (among other things) the type of screen you're drawing the text to. You should read the [`RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING` API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING) for those details.

Comment: Thanks I just edited your code, Concept was correct but setRenderingHits requires Map object. so I changed it to setRenderingHint and constants are in RenderingHints instead of Graphics2D. :)

Comment: Whoops, you're right, though I had accidentally overwritten your edit when I was adding some more details. I fixed it now, `setRenderingHints->setRenderingHint`. Thanks!

Comment: Anti-aliasing should be on by default IMO (it isn't, but someone at Oracle should make it so)