# Line2D decoration tips needed - Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d, graphics2d

I have Line2D and Arc2D objects laid out on my JPanel by Graphics2D drawing. You can have a look a part of it on this question " [How to make pixel perfect Line2D in - Graphics2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329008/how-to-make-pixel-perfect-line2d-in-graphics2d) ". Now what I want to achieve is, I want to create two parallel lines and arcs for all Line2D and Arc2D objects. Visually,

Normal Line2D and Arc2D drawn currently,

[image]

Want to decorate it like this,

[image]

**My Thoughts so far,**

I might be able to achieve this by creating two different line and give an offset +gap and -gap from my normal line position. However This will make lots of objects which I don't want to.

Now, is it possible to make my normal line thicker like this,

[image]

**and give them a border and delete middle bit from it?**

Is it possible to achieve this? if yes, May I please have some direction.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: *"This will make lots of objects"* A 'second line'  (or 100 of them, for a hundred primary lines) is not much to hold in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `BasicStroke` and draw it twice, thicker and thinner.

[image: One line drawn twice]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

class PaintThick {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int size = 150;
        final BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            size,size,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();

        double pad = 20;
        Line2D.Double line1 = new Line2D.Double(
            pad,pad,(double)(size-pad),(double)(size-pad));
        int cap = BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT;
        int join = BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER;
        BasicStroke thick = new BasicStroke(15,cap,join);
        BasicStroke thinner = new BasicStroke(13,cap,join);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,size,size);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setStroke(thick);
        g.draw(line1);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setStroke(thinner);
        g.draw(line1);

        ImageIO.write(bi,"png",new File("img.png"));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @dacwe  What color did you expect?  What color do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the [`Stroke`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Stroke.html) interface  to create a `CompositeStroke`, as shown [here](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/java2d/strokes/).

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * @see http://www.jhlabs.com/java/java2d/strokes/
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342979
 */
class StrokeTest {

    private static final int SIZE = 200;
    private static final double PAD = 20d;

    private static class CompositeStroke implements Stroke {

        private Stroke stroke1, stroke2;

        public CompositeStroke(Stroke stroke1, Stroke stroke2) {
            this.stroke1 = stroke1;
            this.stroke2 = stroke2;
        }

        @Override
        public Shape createStrokedShape(Shape shape) {
            return stroke2.createStrokedShape(
                stroke1.createStrokedShape(shape));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            SIZE, SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Arc2D.Double shape = new Arc2D.Double(PAD, 2 * PAD,
            (SIZE - 2 * PAD), (SIZE - 2 * PAD), 0, 180d, Arc2D.OPEN);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE);
        BasicStroke s1 = new BasicStroke(16f);
        BasicStroke s2 = new BasicStroke(1f);
        g.setStroke(new CompositeStroke(s1, s2));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.draw(shape);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I up-voted that before the code & screen-shot!  Can I have another turn at up-voting?  Nice call on the anti-aliasing.

Comment: Nice thanks, I wish StackOverFlow let user choose how much reputation they want to award :) like there are two answer in front of me and they both are good.