# Java Swing: Drawing curved lines

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw curved lines in Java. A simple bezier curve with an (X,Y) start, an (X,Y) end, and a curve amount would suffice.

I can't find a way to do this in Swing. If it's not in Swing, is there some simple math I can use to do it? And how would I implement it in Swing?

Edit: I'm aware of how to draw shapes and lines by overriding the paint(Graphics g) method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can draw a Bézier curve using the Java 2D Object [Path2D.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html). Just call the method [curveTo(float x1,
                          float y1,
                          float x2,
                          float y2,
                          float x3,
                          float y3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Float.html#curveTo%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) and define the 3 coordinate.

- first Bézier control point
- second Bézier control point
- final end point

Comment: GeneralPath is a legacy class, Path2D.Double/Float is the replacement.

Comment: what is a Bézier ?

Answer (score 4):

Better would be read and following basic tutorial about [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), tons examples are [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm),

- some of examples are outdated by using wrong method `paint()` instead of correct method for painting for `Swing JComponent` `paintComponent()`,
- simple change wrong method `paint()` to the `paintComponent()`,

Comment: One other resource (which includes Bezier curve samples):  http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/samples/suite/

Comment: @paulsm4 [hmmm very nice DJ_Lights, but I think that no :-)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7443911/714968)