# Drawing Arc using two Points as Reference

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, label, points

I already searched over stackoverflow for similar questions, and tried to implement using some suggestions from other answers like this one:

```
Point p1 = prop.getDisplayPoint();
Point p2 = prop2.getDisplayPoint();

int xCenter = p1.x - 50;
int yCenter;

if(p1.y > p2.y)
        yCenter = p1.y - ((p1.y-p2.y)/2);
else
        yCenter = p2.y - ((p2.y-p1.y)/2);

int r = (int)Math.sqrt((p1.x-xCenter)*(p1.x-xCenter) + (p1.y-yCenter)*(p1.y-yCenter));
int x = xCenter-r;
int y = yCenter-r;
int width = 2*r;
int height = 2*r;
int startAngle = (int) ((180/Math.PI)*Math.atan2(p1.y-yCenter, p1.x-xCenter));
int endAngle = (int) ((180/Math.PI)*Math.atan2(p2.y-yCenter, p2.x-xCenter));
g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, endAngle);
```

But still this didnt helped me.
I tried to compute the center of my two points, but the result of the arc was not what I was waiting for.

This was the result:

[image]

This is what I am looking for:

[image: Expected result]

I have the coordinates of each pair of points I want to connect, like the point at "car" and the point at "bus" then I want to draw an arc between them. The angle will always be something like that.

Comment: What does your output look like? I'm guessing a half-circle, but don't want to figure that out from your code.

Comment: The image is just an example, my output has more atoms, but the curves are away far from what I want, they are not even connecting to where is suppose...

Comment: there's a reason that "a picture is worth 1,000 words"; if you're not willing to show a picture (preferably with your "x" and "y" locations identified), then you'll have to come up with the words to replace it. Otherwise, nobody can help you.

Comment: Unless, of course, all you want is to replicate the example picture. In which case, delete your existing code and just say that you want "Teh Codez". You might get a few downvotes, but you'll also probably get what you want.

Comment: You are right! I updated my question, I hope now Its more explicit the problem :) Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the picture, it appears that you have two problems.

The first is that your origin point is incorrect. I haven't tried specific values, but I think it's because you're calculating an arbitrary center based on the first point, and then calculating the start and end of your arcs based on that center point (rather than the actual text locations).

However, I think that the bigger problem is that an arc isn't really appropriate to the task. With an arc, you could go for a semi-circle (or semi-oval), or maybe 1/3 of a circle, but those won't look very good. They certainly won't look like your desired example.

Instead, you want a [Bezier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), so that you can deepen the sides of the "arc". [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562992/java-swing-drawing-curved-lines) a SO question that points you to the docs for the bezier curve functions in Java2D. There are also a bunch of examples if you Google for "java draw bezier".

Comment: Bezier curve made exactly the way I was looking for ;)
Thanks alot mate!

Comment: The solution: QuadCurve2D.Double cubicCurve = new QuadCurve2D.Double( p1.x, p1.y, xCenter, yCenter, p2.x, p2.y);
      g2.draw(cubicCurve);