# Infinity in JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart, infinity

I have found this link: http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6314

Its back in 2007 where they agree that infinity should be supported in JFreeChart.

Anyone know if it is supported or not? I need to be able to support this. Or be able to draw a line on the X axis that doesn't have an end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general support in `JFreeChart` for the *concept* of infinity, other than that offered by `Double`.

The Unicode character ∞, named [`INFINITY` (U+221E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221e/index.htm), may be used to compose a `String` literal. You can also render the glyph, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151403/230513), or obtain an outline using `GlyphVector`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7465829/230513), or via `TextLayout`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513).

For additional guidance, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your intended usage, e.g. title, legend, axis, annotation, label, shape, etc.

Comment: Alright, so what you are saying is that I can draw the symbol instead?

Comment: Yes, you can render the character or its shape anywhere you need it. Alternatively, look for ways to avoid it using a suitable coordinate transformation. There's a related example [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115066).