# Display outline text in matlab gui

Tags: matlab, text

I am working on matlab gui now. 
I would like to display outline text like here :

[image: example of text]

But I can not find it...

Could it be possible to do it in matlab ?
Is there any Option to display outline text ?

I would appreciate for any help/ advice please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB does not support text decoration like this. You would need to specify a `FontName` when creating a `text` object and find a font that has an outline.

```
text(x, y, 'TEST', 'FontName', 'SomeFontWithOutline');
```

Your other option is going to use Java to display and decorate your text for you. [Potentially relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465829/drawing-text-with-outline-in-java)