# Java how to write a text with outline and TextAttribute in the same time

Tags: java, graphics

I'm currently using this way: [Drawing text with outline in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465829/drawing-text-with-outline-in-java)
To write a text with outline, and this to create underline, background color etc: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/TextAttributeUnderlineandstrikethrough.htm

But it doesn't show text attributes if there is outline, when i check `AttributedString#getIterator().getAttributes()` it looks right:

```
{java.awt.font.TextAttribute(strikethrough)=true, java.awt.font.TextAttribute(foreground)=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255], java.awt.font.TextAttribute(font)=java.awt.Font[family=Impact,name=Impact,style=bolditalic,size=80], java.awt.font.TextAttribute(underline)=0}
```

So the attributes are added.

Also I'm using

```
createGlyphVector(<getFontRenderContext>, AttributedString#getIterator)
```

Writes the text with outline correctly, but doesn't show the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `font.createGlyphVector` use `java.awt.font.TextLayout`:

```
TextLayout textlayout = new TextLayout(attributes.getIterator(), graphics.getFontRenderContext());
// the position of the shape at the graphic
Shape shape = textlayout.getOutline(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(xOffset, yOffset));
graphics.setColor(outlineColor);
// Choose another width / strength of the stroke on demand
graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(font.getSize2D() / 10.0f));
// draw the outline / stroke
graphics.draw(shape);
// draw / fill the letters / text
graphics.setColor(textColor);
graphics.fill(shape);
```