# Clear foreground of a drawing panel in Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

Making [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137465/mouseevent-on-jpanel-wrong-coordinate) paintbrush program I decided I want to clear the panel container (`panel2` in the linked code). I used `PanelName.setForeground(null)` and it worked. What I'd like to know is if there are known drawbacks of this approach and other ways of removing graphics objects from the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you override `paintComponent`, you can clear its `Graphics` using [`Graphics#clearRect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). But overall, I prefer your approach because mine would require you to either subclass `JPanel`, or anonymously declare one.

Answer (score 3):

The converse of @mre's answer is that "It is up to the look and feel to honor this [property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setForeground%28java.awt.Color%29), some may choose to ignore it." I don't know of a `PanelUI` that ignores the foreground color, but it's something to be aware of when testing.

Addendum: As @kleopatra comments, the [`JComponent@setForeground()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setForeground%28java.awt.Color%29) API links to the [`Component#getForeground()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getForeground%28%29) API, which notes the following: "if this component does not have a foreground color, the foreground color of its parent is returned."