# Replacing JSlider by Knob in java applications

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jslider

It is very common that we use JSliders in our java applications. But I want to replace JSliders by knobs. I need some guidance to study in this respect.

Comment: You need to ask a more precise question.

Comment: @kviiri   I am using JSlider adding change listner to it for catching change events in java stand alone application. I want to replace JSlider by knob. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

**Preable: Not sure how good knobs are for the usability of the UI. I would avoid them if not for touch screen interfaces.**

The is no Java support for components like Knobs so you have to create your own.
[Here](http://users.dickinson.edu/~braught/courses/cs132f00/classes/code/JKnob.src.html) you can find a basic example with a really simple graphic but that consist in proof of concept.

If you want to edit that code some suggestions that I give you are:

- Change the `paint` method for the `paintComponent`. If you don't know why [here the explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175174/paintcomponent-vs-paint-and-jpanel-vs-canvas-in-a-paintbrush-type-gui)
- Use the antialiasing adding the following line of code at the beginning of the `paintComponent` method. The picture shows you the difference.

[image: Normal vs Antialiasing]

> ```
>    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
>    g2.setRenderingHints(
>      new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
>    );
> ```