# Drawing shapes from an arraylist

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, mouselistener

I am trying to draw at my mouse a certain shape that I have set. I defined some shapes where they extend shape and draw circles and stuff. But when I click on panel it seems the paint doesnt put anything on the white jpanel. Debugger tells me shapes are saved though.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    currentX = e.getX();

    currentY = e.getY();

    Shape newShape = owner.currentBrush.clone();
    picture.add(newShape); 
    repaint();
}
public void paint(Graphics g){

        super.paint(g);
        for( int i = 0; i < myShapes.size(); i++ ){
            picture.get(i).draw(g); 
        }

    }

public void draw(Graphics g){
        Graphics g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        g2d.fillOval(getX(), getY(), radius, radius);

        g.drawOval(getX(), getY(), radius, radius);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible I am painting under my setBackground which I put as white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overriding `paint()` method use `paintComponent()` method for `JPanel`.

```
@Overrie
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     //your custom painting here
}
```

Read more

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [paintComponent() vs paint() and JPanel vs Canvas in a paintbrush-type GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175174/paintcomponent-vs-paint-and-jpanel-vs-canvas-in-a-paintbrush-type-gui)

Comment: It seems to have the same problem@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        for( int i = 0; i < owner.myDraw.picture.size(); i++ ){
            owner.myDraw.picture.get(i).draw(g); 
            //System.out.println("I BET THIS NEVER PRINTS");
        }
     
        
        System.out.println("I AM TRYING TO PAINT");

Comment: why are you using `g.drawOval()` and `g2d.fillOval()` where both Graphics are used that draws at same location.

Comment: I think you have to spend some time to study about Swing application and custom painting. Any online stuff will never help you at all.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aav73i7x realized I was adding a new jpanel, but doesnt seem to be the problem

Comment: Just create a simple test program and try to replicate this issue.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/paintproject a better way to see it. It is so close to working. I put so much time into this thing.

Comment: Was working the whole time. Just didn't update the x and y setters.