# java.lang.NullPointerException on show image into JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, nullpointerexception, paint

I tried to do a program that just show an image, everything goes right but the console shows this warning...
The image shows fine but i wanna know what is the console warning and how to solve it
Here my main class...

```
    public class main extends JFrame{
     Image ryu;
     imagen objRyu;
     public main(){
            super("Imagen1");
            this.setSize(500,500);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setResizable(true);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            objRyu = new imagen(ryu,"images/Ryu.png",100,100);
            repaint();

        }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new main();

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
         g2.setColor(Color.gray);
         g2.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
         g2.drawImage(objRyu.getImagen(), 100, 50, objRyu.getAncho(), objRyu.getAlto(), null);


    }

}
```

my imagen class

```
 public class imagen {
    InputStream imgStream;
    private Image imagen;
    private int ancho;
    private int alto;

    public imagen(Image imagen, String ruta,int ancho, int alto){
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.ancho = ancho;
        this.alto = alto;

        try{
            imgStream = imagen.class.getResourceAsStream(ruta);
            this.imagen = ImageIO.read(imgStream);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public int getAncho() {
        return ancho;
    }

    public int getAlto() {
        return alto;
    }

    public Image getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }
```

and the console log...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.paint(main.java:34)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.paint(main.java:34)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The problem is `g2.drawImage()` here. Simply debug it and find out which object is `null`.

Comment: but only have one object the image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overridden `paint()` method is called immediately after calling `setVisible(true)` method and at that point object `objRyu` is `null`.

---

#### Some Points:

1. Don't directly paint on `JFrame` instead use a container such as `JPanel` and add it in `JFrame`.
2. Instead of overriding `paint()` method use `paintComponent()` method for `JPanel`.

   ```
   @Overrie
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //your custom painting here
   }
   ```
3. Call `JFrame.setVisible()` in the end after adding all the component.
4. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

   Read more

   - [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
   - [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)
5. Don't extend any class until and unless you are modifying the existing logic.

   Read more

   - [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

---

Read more

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [paintComponent() vs paint() and JPanel vs Canvas in a paintbrush-type GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175174/paintcomponent-vs-paint-and-jpanel-vs-canvas-in-a-paintbrush-type-gui)

Answer (score 4):

The error indicates that objRyu is null. As soon as any Swing component becomes visible, it is painted and later refreshed again.

```
//make this happen early
            objRyu = new imagen(ryu,"images/Ryu.png",100,100);
// this should be last
            this.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it , just change the object call after the constructor

```
public class main extends JFrame{
 Image ryu;
 imagen objRyu;
 public main(){
        super("Imagen1");
        objRyu = new imagen(ryu,"images/Ryu.png",100,100);
        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    }
```

Comment: No, follow and understand what @braj is telling you.