# Is it better to use JPanel or Canvas?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, bufferstrategy

Right now I have a workspace set up that extends JFrame and implements Runnable. It actually set it up that way when I used the JFrame feature within eclipse. I try to add a BufferStrategy and I get several errors in the Debug console.

Comment: Which you should use will depend on what you want to achieve

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175174/paintcomponent-vs-paint-and-jpanel-vs-canvas-in-a-paintbrush-type-gui/12175819#12175819) can help

Comment: The answer will depend on what you want to achieve. If you want complete control over the painting process, you'll want to use Canvas and BufferStrategy, if you want to use Swing based controls as well, you'll need to use s JPanel

Comment: I'm wanting to use custom images that I store in a src folder and get the image from there and display it on my JPanel within the project I am working on. I already have a custom background. Maybe I am trying this the wrong way.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). Unless you doing some intensive animation (and I do mean intensive), you don't really need to use `Canvas` or `BufferStrategy`