# Background color for JPanel replaced by grey when method paint() added

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I code the following basic Java Swing example which is a JPanel with blue background:

```java
public class Chart1 extends JFrame {
    
    private MainPanel1 main;    
    
    public Chart1() throws InterruptedException {
        
        setSize(600,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        // CREATE AND ADD MAIN PANEL
        main = new MainPanel1();
        this.getContentPane().add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        // DRAW WINDOW
        this.setVisible(true);
                        
    }
    
}
```

```java
public class MainPanel1 extends JPanel {        
    
    public MainPanel1() {
        
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        
    }
}
```

I get the following result:

[image: Blue JPanel]

So far, so good.

Now I add a `paint()` method. The source code is as follows:

```java
public class MainPanel1 extends JPanel {        
    
    public MainPanel1() {
        
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    }

}
```

Then even without doing anything in `paint()` I get a grey background, why? how can I fix this?

[image: JPanel with paint]

Comment: You could put `super.paint(g)` inside your overridden paint method. That will go ahead with the normal paint code that fills in the background colour. Also usual advice is to override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that paint (a java 1.0 - 1.1 method) calls paintBackground in JComponents. When you overrode it, it isn't calling all of the swing paint methods. But if you add super.paint(g), it will look like it did before.

Also - please note that the default ContentPane in JFrame is already a JPanel. Rather than replacing the ContentPane with your JPanel, you could just call:

```
((JPanel) myFrame.getContentPane()).setBackground(Color.blue);
```

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies. For the ContentPane/JPanel, this is a simplified version for SO, the actual code contains 3 panels so I need this JPanel.

Comment: @M.E. Glad this has helped you. One piece of advice: In general (and when/where possible), it is better to use out of the box Swing / View components (no extending) and put the entire control of the GUI in its own class; it makes debugging easier. Though if you are creating reusable swing components (For instance ColorButton (A Swing extension for allowing the user to configure a color property, in a config window for example) here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/) it makes sense for the component itself to contain the logic

Answer (score 1):

You should not be overriding `paint` but `paintComponent`.  The problem would still occur so you need to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`

So Change your paint method to the following.

```
public class MainPanel1 extends JPanel {        
    
    public MainPanel1() {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         // The following statement ensures that
         // the background color will be applied
         // as well as other preparations for 
         // doing graphics.
 
         super.paintComponent(g);
         // If you have other graphics
         // code, add it here.
   }

}
```

And do not subclass `JFrame` in the `Chart1` class. It is bad practice. Use an instance.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Comment: Helpful comment. I also saw this after reading your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175174/paintcomponent-vs-paint-and-jpanel-vs-canvas-in-a-paintbrush-type-gui